# Injecting Singleton class using Dagger 2.x

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have two components, one for Application Context and one for Activity Context as shown below.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class,})

public interface AppComponent {
    @ForApplication
    Context context();

    //Preferences prefs(); //(Question is related to this line)
}

@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class,modules = {ActivityModule.class})
public interface ActivityComponent extends AppComponent {
  void inject(ActivityA activity);
}
```

I have a Singleton class that I want to inject in ActivityA that is declared in ActivityComponent.

```
@Singleton
public class Preferences {
@Inject
    public Preferences(@ForApplication Context context) {
        ...
    }
}

public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Inject
        Preferences preferences;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                        .appComponent(((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent())
                        .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                        .build();

}
```

I am injecting AppComponent in my Applicaiton `onCreate()` and `ActivityComponent` in onCreate of Activity, in this case ActivityA like above

*Problem(or Question):* Currently, If I do not expose this singleton class from my `AppComponent` (The commented line in first code block) and do not have provides method in AppModule. I cannot compile. Compilation Error shows I cannot have a reference to different scope from `ActivityComponent`, which I kind of understand. That means, I cannot access Singleton scoped class with PerActivity scoped component.

But, do I have to have provides method for all Singleton class and expose it via `AppComponent` (which I am currently doing and works)? Is there a better way to do the Singleton class injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way. Declare `Activity` component as `Application` [subcomponent](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html). This way everything declared in `Application` component is visible in `Activity` subcomponent.
Access to the `Activity` subcomponent can be done through `Acpplication` component:

```
GithubClientApplication.get(this)
            .getAppComponent()
            .provide(new ActivityModule(this))
```

Have a look at this excellent [article](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/) about Dagger components, especially in **Implementation** section.

Comment: Thanks. Subcomponent approach is much cleaner. I moved to subcomponent approach.